# 3 DataGridViews interlinking issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I am having three Datagridviews in my windows Form. One brings the data of Villages, on clicking any cell, Second Datagridview is populated with Customer Details. On clicking the customer name, third Datagridview must populate and calculate the balance of customer, whether credit is remaining or advance is deposited, now where I am facing problem is the third datagridview.

It specifically throws exception: Object reference set to null.

```
    private void dataGridView3_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        double loansum1 = 0;
        double emisum1 = 0;
        double dd1 = 0;
        double ei1 = 0;
        double finalsum = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow drr1 in dataGridView3.Rows)
        {
            if (drr1.Cells[1].Selected == true)
            {
                string customerid = drr1.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                label1.Text = customerid;
                SqlConnection setcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sismanager"].ConnectionString);
                using (SqlCommand getsup = new SqlCommand("SELECT Ciid, Cdate, Cparticulars, Ccr, Cdr FROM Customerbills WHERE Cid = @Cid ORDER BY Cdate DESC", setcon))
                {
                    getsup.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", customerid);
                    SqlDataAdapter drrr = new SqlDataAdapter(getsup);
                    try
                    {
                        setcon.Open();
                        DataTable data1 = new DataTable();
                        drrr.Fill(data1);

                        if (data1.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.DataSource = data1;
                            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Bill Number";
                            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Bill Date";
                            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Particulars";
                            dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Credit Balance";
                            dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Cash Balance";

                            for (int ij = 0; ij < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count); ++ij)
                            {
                                dd1 = Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[ij].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                                ei1 = Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[ij].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                                loansum1 += dd1;
                                emisum1 += ei1;
                            }
                            label4.Text = (Math.Round(loansum1)).ToString();
                            label5.Text = (Math.Round(emisum1)).ToString();
                            finalsum = (emisum1 - loansum1);
                            if (finalsum >= 0)
                            {
                                label6.Text = "Rs. " + finalsum + " (Previous Amount Clear)";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                label6.Text = "Rs. " + finalsum + " (Previous Amount Due)";
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    catch (SqlException exx)
                    {

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        setcon.Close();
                    }

              }

            }

        }
    }
```

The exception error comes at:

```
    dd1 = Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[ij].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
```

[Error Image below; It shows in call stack that the data is coming.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7y3p.jpg)

Comment: First use Ciid as Bill_Number which will change header to real name.  Second the column type is the same as database.  So if database already has the dd1 as a number there is no need to parse.  If it is a string then there is no need to use Value.ToString() just Value is needed.  When you do Value.ToString() you get the type name in Net which is "string".

Comment: Sir, I tried changing it from: 

        dd1 = Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[ij].Cells[3].Value.ToString());

to 

dd1 = Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[ij].Cells[3].Value);

But it is in red now and shows parsing error.

However, when I am running it in other application with similar code, its working. But it is giving problem here. I compared the codes too. They are same to same.

Comment: Compare the types of the variables in the database.  The types are not the same.

Comment: Looks like `dataGridView1.Rows[ij].Cells[3].Value` is null. You need to see why it is null and make sure it is populated or check it for null before you try to parse it to double

Comment: Great Sir, I was unable to interpret the problem earlier. I used if clause inside the loop and set it to check for null value of variables from the cell and to set it to 0.0 if it is. And the problem was sorted as you both told.